# footer with absolute position - responsive design

Tags: css, html, position, footer, absolute

I have a little problem with my responsive design. I am using a normal `<footer>` with this style.

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
```

It works fine and when I am using a smaller screen I have to scroll, that's normal.

The problem is that the `<footer>` is not at the bottom. It is in the middle of the screen. Like `margin-top: 100%` of the full screen, without scrolling.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks!

Comment: Please search the site before posting, this has been asked a ton of times before. You are looking for [**Sticky footer**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/).

Comment: thanks! I don't remember the word "sticky".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Position fixed, This may look something like this

```
 footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to position the element fixed to the bottom. Set the bottom offset with bottom or margin-bottom parameters.

You could go with this:

```
footer {
    position:fixed;
    height:20px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I get your problem correctly. Your problem is that the footer is at the middle of the screen when there is little content in that page, right?

To solve the problem, you should make the parent element take up the full screen. For example,

```
<head>
<style>
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    some other content
</div>
<footer>
    Some content inside footer
</footer>
</body>
```

Or if you don't mind the footer is always visible at the bottom of the screen, use position:fixed . Then you don't need to consider the height of the parent element.